# How can I change the text color of a UISearchBar's cancel button?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UISearchController` in my iOS app. When the user taps on its `UISearchBar` the keyboard pops up and a cancel button is presented. How can change the text color of the cancel button?

Comment: just set the tint color.

Comment: That works. Set that as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the tint color of the search bar. :) As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self])).tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```